# How to use available RAM?

Tags: 16.04, performance, ram, memory-usage

My computer running Ubuntu 16.04 has 32GB RAM, but even on heavy tasks, rarely over 8GB is consumed.

I wonder if is possible to tell Ubuntu to use more RAM to speed up the process.

Moreover, after a day of working, my computer is slowing down, and needs a reboot. Is it normal? Can't Ubuntu fresh itself up when resources are abundant?

Comment: You can't really do this.  Applications create what they need and use in memory, and nothing more.  Creating more would be useless data.  It's like asking someone who is holding a cup of water to fill a barrel with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tell Ubuntu to use more RAM to speed up the process

Ubuntu does not control what the applications you're using do with available memory, the applications themselves do. So you'd need to find some way to tell the application you're using that it shold use more memory. However, most applications only use as much memory as they actually need - using more isn't going to improve performance. (What applications are you using, though ?)

---

However, what Ubuntu *does* do is use unused, available RAM as cache, i.e. recently accessed files are kept in memory, so that when they are needed again, they do not need to be fetched from disk. This improves performance. This is also why starting an application (e.g web browser or IDE) a second time is faster that starting it "cold", i.e. immediately after boot.

> After a day of working, my computer is slowing down [...]

No, this isn't normal. I generally have weeks of uptime on my Linux systems, and performance isn't affected. Maybe check the memory / CPU usage at the end of the day, and see if something is using lots of resources. What do you mean by "*is slowing down*", though ?

Comment: I meant when opening an app takes 1s in fresh boot, it takes 3s when the computer is on for a day.

Comment: @All, try to look at `top` output if something strange is going on. Concentrate on process that use a lot of CPU and/or a lot of memory. Add this info in your question.